How to Save UTC DateTime in SQL Server with 'Z' Suffix or UTC Offset for Accurate Frontend Conversion
I have a DateTime variable with the value 2024-08-12T18:30:00, which is in UTC. While inserting this value into SQL Server, I want to ensure it retains the UTC designation. Specifically, I'd like the value to be stored as 2024-08-12T18:30:00.000Z (where the "Z" indicates UTC), or alternatively, with an explicit offset like 2024-08-12 18:30:00.0000000 +00:00.
On the frontend, I'm using JavaScript's new Date() function, which automatically converts the date to the local time based on the presence of "Z" or the offset.
I am using INSERT INTO function, How can I ensure that the date is saved in SQL Server with the "Z" or with the UTC offset, so that it correctly indicates UTC time?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So use datetimeoffset.

Are all of the times you're storing UTC? If so, I would (and have) omit the time zone and just store it as a datetime or datetime2 (no offset). Why? The TZ is implicit in that case and you can account for it elsewhere (e.g. in your javascript code). datetimeoffset is useful when the data could have different offsets and you want to either convert them to other TZs or you want to do duration calculations (which is just another conversion).

DATETIMEOFFSET data type deals with time zones:
Create Table tbl (id INT, datetime_dt DATETIME, dt_offset_dt DATETIMEOFFSET );
Insert Into tbl 
  Select 1, '2024-08.31 12:00:00', '2024-08-31 12:00:00 +00:00' Union All
  Select 2, '2024-08.31 12:00:00', '2024-08-31 12:00:00.0000000 +02:00' ;
Select    *   From      tbl

id  datetime_dt              dt_offset_dt
--  -----------------------  ----------------------------------
 1  2024-08-31 12:00:00.000  2024-08-31 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00
 2  2024-08-31 12:00:00.000  2024-08-31 12:00:00.0000000 +02:00

